# Visual Studio C++ and the max macro

Tags: visual-c++

Somewhere in our codebase, there is an include file - possibly a system include - which is itself including the system file defining the legacy C max symbol:

```
#define max(a,b) (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b)
```

Yes, macros are horrid. Not my circus etc. The problem is that some of our source code use

```
#include <limits>

int x = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

but at this point the preprocessor uses the aforementioned macro to textually replace that function call and compilation fails, obviously. So we have to

```
 #undef max
```

near the start of the code block, which is also horrible. Is there a way of finding out which include file is including the file (that includes the file...) where the max macro is defined? Or is there a better way of dealing with this?

Comment: There are probably numerous 'standard' headers (e.g. `stdlib.h`) that potentially define the 'max' and 'min' macros. Try right-clicking on it in a source file and select "go to definition" from the pop-up menu.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes it's in <stdlib.h> but we're not directly including that - we need to identify the SOAB that is. It might be <memory> which is a bummer.

Comment: I have 'resorted' to having `#undef min` and `#undef max` in my projects' 'global' header file, after all the required system #includes (but before the c++ STL includes).

Comment: I have `#include <memory>` (and all other STL headers) **after** the `#undef` lines, and that works well.

Comment: Or you can define the `_CRT_DECLARE_NONSTDC_NAMES` macro to `0` (possibly on the compiler command line with `/D_CRT_DECLARE_NONSTDC_NAMES=0`) to prevent the old-style headers from defining (lowercase) `min` and `max` - but that may have other, undesired consequences.

Comment: Define `NOMINMAX` in your project settings. These macros are defined in Windows headers somewhere, and that macro prevents that.